# Balanced impedance CM and DM stages EMI Filtering

Tags: noise, common-mode, emi-filtering

Here is the following assertion : [image]

I would like to understand why line impedance imbalance can cause CM noise to get converted into DM noise ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: have you read what you wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a DC voltage source with two equal resistors R1 and R2 connected at its + and - Terminals and a load resistor RL connecting R1 and R2.

The voltage source is the common mode signal (or CM noise).

Now if you slightly change R1 or R2, the load resistor RL will get a different voltage despite the fact that you did not change the common mode DC voltage source.